# How to Add a Quantity Column on a DataGrid from ListView selection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've a ListView whose data I select and send to a DataGrid. I am having trouble with the quantity column of the DataGrid which I would want to calculate how many times a ListView item has been added to the said DataGrid (I'm currently displaying a success message when the same item is selected). I would also want to calculate the price and the quantity and display them on one column named 'price' the DataGrid.

Here is the Datagrid

```xaml
 <ListView x:Name="ItemGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="ItemGridView_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">    
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
           <GridViewColumn>                                                        
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <Grid Margin="5">
                             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                             <Image Source="{Binding ItemImage}" Width="225" Height="157" Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="DownOnly" />

                             <StackPanel Margin="0,100,0,0">
                               <Border Margin="-0,-7,0,0"  Height="63" Width="225" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                                   <TextBlock Margin="8" FontWeight="Heavy" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                               </Border>
                                <TextBlock Margin="15,-28,0,0" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding SellingPrice}" Foreground="White"/>
                             </StackPanel>
                         </Grid>                                                                    
                     </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>                                               
</ListView>
```

The DataGrid to which the data is sent looks like this:

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="DGItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="350" MaxHeight="350" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="3" Header="#" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={global:RowToIndexConverter}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Items" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding SellingPrice}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty"  />           
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The code behind to send the datan following a ListView double click event is as below:

```c#
 private void ItemGridView_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
      var selectedItem = ItemGridView.SelectedItem;

      if (!DGItems.Items.Contains(selectedItem))
      {
          DGItems.Items.Add(selectedItem);
      }
      else
      {
          utilityMethods.InformationMessage("Attempted to add item successfully");                
      }

 }
```

I've included screenshots to preview how the application looks just to put the question in context.

[image: Sale Screen Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working sample. I made slight modifications to your xaml and bindings to show how it can be done.  Whenever you double-click an item in the ListView, it will update both the Quantity and Total columns in the DataGrid.

[image]

**MyItem.cs: This is a simple model to replicate your food item**

```
namespace UpdateQuantityColumnTest
{
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public double SellingPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ListViewItemViewModel.cs: This is a view model representation of your MyItem for the ListView**

```
namespace UpdateQuantityColumnTest
{
    public class ListViewItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ListViewItemViewModel(MyItem model)
        {
            this.Model = model;
        }

        public MyItem Model { get; private set; }

        public string ItemName { get => this.Model.ItemName; set { this.Model.ItemName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string SellingPrice { get => this.Model.SellingPrice.ToString("c"); }
    }
}
```

**DGItemViewModel: This is a slightly different view model representation of your MyItem for the DataGrid, but includes a Quantity and a TotalPrice**

```
namespace UpdateQuantityColumnTest
{
    public class DGItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private int quantity;

        public DGItemViewModel(MyItem model)
        {
            this.Model = model;
            this.quantity = 1; // always start at 1
        }

        public MyItem Model { get; private set; }
        public string ItemName { get => this.Model.ItemName; set { this.Model.ItemName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string SellingPrice { get => this.Model.SellingPrice.ToString("c"); }
        public int Quantity { get => this.quantity; set { this.quantity = value; OnPropertyChanged(); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalPrice)); } }
        public string TotalPrice { get => (this.Model.SellingPrice * this.Quantity).ToString("c"); }
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase.cs: This is the base class that simply handles the INotifyPropertyChanged to update the UI whenever one of the property values change in your view model**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace UpdateQuantityColumnTest
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml: I made slight changes, mainly to your bindings so that my sample could work**

```
<Window x:Class="UpdateQuantityColumnTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="ItemGridView_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid Margin="5">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Image Source="{Binding ItemImage}" Width="225" Height="157" Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="DownOnly" />
                                        <StackPanel Margin="0,100,0,0">
                                            <Border Margin="-0,-7,0,0"  Height="63" Width="225" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                                                <TextBlock Margin="8" FontWeight="Heavy" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                                            </Border>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="15,-28,0,0" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding SellingPrice}" Foreground="White"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DGItems" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckoutItems}" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="350" MaxHeight="350" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Items" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding SellingPrice}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty"  Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total"  Binding="{Binding TotalPrice}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs: The code-behind that does all the work**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UpdateQuantityColumnTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> items;
        private ObservableCollection<DGItemViewModel> checkoutItems;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.items == null)
                    this.items = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel>();
                return this.items;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DGItemViewModel> CheckoutItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.checkoutItems == null)
                    this.checkoutItems = new ObservableCollection<DGItemViewModel>();
                return this.checkoutItems;
            }
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Populate with dummy data
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel(new MyItem() { ItemName = "Beef Steak", SellingPrice = 1000 }));
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel(new MyItem() { ItemName = "Bacon Brie", SellingPrice = 1200 }));
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel(new MyItem() { ItemName = "Bread and Sausage", SellingPrice = 700 }));
        }

        private void ItemGridView_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = ItemGridView.SelectedItem as ListViewItemViewModel;
            var checkoutItem = this.CheckoutItems.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ItemName == selectedItem.ItemName);

            if (checkoutItem == null)
            {
                this.CheckoutItems.Add(new DGItemViewModel(selectedItem.Model));
            }
            else
            {
                //utilityMethods.InformationMessage("Attempted to add item successfully");
                checkoutItem.Quantity++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the items in the ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}" collection have an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and notify about the change of their properties, then you can solve this problem with minimal changes.

Add an int Qty property to the element class and change your method:

```
        if (!DGItems.Items.Contains(selectedItem))
        {
            DGItems.Items.Add(selectedItem);
            selectedItem.Qty = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedItem.Qty++;
            utilityMethods.InformationMessage("Attempted to add item successfully");
        }
```

And add a binding to this property in the column:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="3" Header="#" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={global:RowToIndexConverter}}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Items" Binding="{Binding ItemName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding SellingPrice}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Qty}" />           
</DataGrid.Columns>
```